# CAKEPHP ORM Feature

Tags: php, orm, cakephp

Is CakePHP allow to generate tables from classes (or) it has to be always tables first and then map classes to those tables?  Many thanks,

Answer (score -1):

If you want to stick with PHP then Symfony is the way to go, I'm sure Ruby is nice too if you want to learn another language.